# Change the style of a certain text of textarea

Tags: codenameone

I've a textArea with grow limit "2" and alignment "center". I need to hightlight the "Quick Booking" text of the following textArea differently ie. in color, size etc. Since the textArea is aligned center, this hightlighted text may appear anywhere as per the device width. How can I do that?

```
TextArea ta = new TextArea("Need urgent fix for your car ? We will get to you asap Quick Booking");
ta.setUIID("small");
ta.setEditable(false);
ta.setGrowByContent(true);
ta.setGrowLimit(2);
ta.getAllStyles().setAlignment(Label.CENTER);
```

How It is now...

[image]

How it should be...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That isn't supported. One option is to use a `BrowserComponent` for this element and format it with HTML. Another is to use a rich text view such as this: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-lightweight-rich-text-view.html

Comment: I couldn't make it work through richTextView but I solved it as in above answer. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I saw the stack question where it was solved. I didn't find it now otherwise I'd have shared the link. It works though.

```
homeContainer.add(FlowLayout.encloseCenter(lbl1, new Label("urgent"), new Label("fix"), new Label(" for"), new Label("your"), new Label("car? "), new Label("We"), new Label("will"), new Label("get"), new Label("to"), new Label("you"), new Label("asap "), clickable));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this is not supported.I would suggest you to give a look on below article

```
https://medium.com/@Cuong.Le/android-rich-text-overview-397e6af529d9
```